# Unresponsive save dialogs in Preview

Tags: macos, preview, autosave

With the introduction of Mountain Lion, Preview acts up whenever I need to save a file.  It does this regardless of whether I use File > Save or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.  The logs tell the same story:

```
10/20/12 10:54:48.700 PM Preview[56917]: RVS:__54-[NSRemoteSavePanel _runOrderingOperationWithContext:]_block_invoke_0319 : Timeout occured while waiting for the window
```

Right after Preview stops responding, this log shows up and I can use Preview normally again.  This also occurs when I try to `Move to...`  from the window menu.

I have all of Mountain Lion's latest updates. Is this a bug just like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62451/can-mountain-lion-be-modified-so-that-a-double-click-will-open-hidden-folders) and is Apple aware of it?  Is anyone else experiencing these issues and are there known workarounds (besides quitting and re-opening Preview [although it *does* save your work and annotations right before, because of Auto Save...?] or using [Skitch](http://skitch.com/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a recent restore and fixing permissions and the disk in Disk Utility have cleared up the issue. If it does happen again, however, I will return to this post with a bounty. Also, a recent OS X update seems to have eliminated the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled **Documents & Data** in **System Preferences > iCloud** to make this problem go away.